# Can't run a python program in terminal? [Mac OSX]

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'm trying to execute a python program from Terminal but it isn't working.
Something like:

```
x = 5
```

Then typing:

```
UserName:Documents UserName$ python simple.py
```

Outputs:

```
UserName:Documents UserName$
```

Without actually executing/opening the file.

But if I have a program like:

```
x = input('Something: ')
```

Then it shows up in terminal, such as:

```
UserName:Documents UserName$ python simple.py

Something:
```

Probably a silly question, but been trying to fix it for the last 1.5 hours and can't find a workable solution.

Comment: What happens if you do `print("Hello world")` ?

Comment: It prints fine: UserName:Documents UserName$ python simple.py
hello world

Comment: Why do you think `python simple.py` doesn't work when simple.py is `x=5`? It works.. you just can't see anything because there is no showable result.

Comment: @Hexoul I was probably expecting the wrong thing :/ I thought that I could get IDLE-esque 'Run Module' functionality in terminal?

Comment: Did you expect about some message like "===== RESTART ====" when `Run Module` on IDLE?

Comment: Yeah something similar to how IDLE does 'Run Module' but in terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short program

```
x = 5
```

gets run and then Python exits back to the command line. No problem there, it all works correctly. If you want to *stay* inside the interpreter, start your program with

```
python -i simple.py
```

When running that, you will get the usual interpreter prompt after it is finished:

```
>>>
```

and you can see it *did* run, because `x` got the expected value:

```
>>> x
5
>>> x*x*x*x/(x+x+x-x/x)-x/x-x/x
42
```

Also, from inside the interpreter, you can load-and-run your file again:

```
>>> execfile('simple.py')
>>> x
5
```

See Bojan Nikolic's [Running Python Programs from the Command-line](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python-running-cline.html) for a number of other startup options.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is working exactly as written... but maybe not as intended... The input prompt asks you to enter a value...

maybe you want to add a print so that you get a feedback that your program does something:

```
x = input('Something: ')
print(x)
```

if you are using python 2.x:

```
x = raw_input('Something: ')
print x
```

Then, on the prompt, input a value and press `enter`

Comment: "but maybe not as intended" -- you're probably right. My premise was probably wrong, it's my understanding that I can do IDLE-esque 'running' of programs in Terminal, that might be the issue? It doesn't work like that?

Comment: What does `IDLE-esque 'running' of programs` mean? Have you tried the suggestion above? Did it work?

Comment: Similar to 'Run -> Run Module' in IDLE